# Tira-teimas para o uso da expressão ‘tira-teimas’?

Tags: uso-de-palavras, expressões

Que diferentes usos pode ter a expressão *tira-teimas*? Procurei no dicionário da [Priberam](http://www.priberam.pt/dlpo/tira-teimas), e não encontrei frases que exemplificassem os diferentes usos.

Será que poderiam dar-mos? Além disso, será que o meu uso dessa expressão, no título da questão, está correcto?

Comment: Conheço a expressão "tira-teima", no singular.

Comment: @Centaurus só encontrei registo de tira-teimas  http://www.priberam.pt/dlpo/tira-teimas

Comment: Fiz uma consulta ao [**google-books**.](https://www.google.com.br/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#tbm=bks&q=%22tira-teimas%22) e encontrei 1290 entradas para "tira-teimas" e 2080 para "tira-teima".   As duas formas parecem existir mas "tira-teima" parece ser mais comum.

Comment: Old man,   veja o [**link**](https://books.google.com.br/books?id=OOCSYWCKv4wC&pg=PA751&dq=%22tira-teimas%22&hl=pt-BR&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiFu4684YzPAhXMjpAKHbJkAIMQ6AEIIjAB#v=onepage&q=%22tira-teimas%22&f=false)

Comment: Centaurus, obrigado pelos links, mas não tenho acesso ao livro...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

De facto o [Priberam](http://www.priberam.pt/dlpo/tira-teimas) é um bocado seco e incompleto acerca de *tira-teimas*. Deixo aqui as definições do Houaiss (Lisboa, 2003), que tem *tira-teimas* e *tira-teima* (desabreviando algumas abreviaturas):

> **tira-teimas** *s.m.2n* (1881 cf. CA1) **1** *informal* prova categórica; argumento irrefutável  **2** *por extensão, informal* dicionário **3** *informal* (1881) qualquer objeto usado para castigar (vara, cacete etc.) **4** juiz, pessoa que dirime uma questão ***#*** *s2g.2n* Brasil, sudeste **5** aguardente de cana; cachaça, tira-meima
>
> **tira-teima** *s.m.* (1858 cf. MS6) **1** mesmo que *TIRA-TEIMAS* (‘prova categórica’, ‘dicionário’, ‘objeto’) **2** *informal* arma de fogo portátil; revólver, pistola **3** Desporto, Brasil, lance ou jogo entre adversários para decidir quem é o melhor **4** TV Brasil, recurso eletrónico que analisa trechos selecionados de imagens gravadas, especialmente lances de competições desportivas, avaliando detalhes que tenham suscitado dúvidas na exibição em velocidade normal ***#*** *s2g.* Brasil, sudeste **5** mesmo que *TIRA-TEIMAS* (‘aguardente de cana’)

As única aceções que eu conhecia são a 1 e 4 de *tira-teimas* (‘prova categórica’, ‘juiz’). O contexto é uma disputa qualquer, e o **tira-teimas** é o que vem decidir quem tem razão. Eis alguns exemplos (grafia original; meu negrito):

> Branca, desdenhosa e ironica. Com que então Pilatos era Romano? Porque não dizeis que era o Papa?
>   Pero, fulminado pelo argumento. É verdade… Pois quem me disse isto foi o capellão de Chaul.
>   Branca, vendo entrar fr. João de Tara. Ahi vem o **tira-teimas**… Ó snr. fr. João, Pilatos era judeu?
>   [(M. Pinheiro Chagas, *A Judia, drama original em 5 actos*, 1869.)](https://books.google.pt/books?id=qEtgAAAAcAAJ&pg=PA16&dq=%22tira-teimas%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwj1gr7y54zPAhXBWRQKHVelBNg4ZBDoAQiGAjAi#v=onepage&q=%22tira-teimas%22&f=false)
>
> Bento: Sim minha fidalga. E a proposito de papeladas, saiba que me deve um dinheirão.
>   Condessa: Ora essa!
>   Bento *(Puxando da carteira)*: O **tira-teimas** está aqui: 3 certidões — quem a manda ser casamenteira ? — 1$200 ; esmola ao sineiro da Graça, coxo : 500 réis ; para a festa da Conceição do Conventinho : 2$000 réis ;
>   [(*Marqueza de Verride, comedia-drama em 4 actos*, 1895)](https://books.google.pt/books?id=yP4AAAAAMAAJ&q=%22E%20a%20proposito%20de%20papeladas,%20saiba%22&dq=%22E%20a%20proposito%20de%20papeladas,%20saiba%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiCsb3d4ozPAhXGsxQKHbV6B88Q6AEIHTAA%20https://books.google.pt/books?id=yP4AAAAAMAAJ&q=%22tira-teimas%22&dq=%22tira-teimas%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiH2eWs4IzPAhVDuRQKHYGKD2g4lgEQ6AEI4wEwIA)

As aceções **3** e **4** de *tira-teima* (‘jogo para decidir quem é melhor’, ‘câmara lenta’) são desenvolvimentos mais recentes das aceções ‘prova categórica’ e ‘juiz’, e pelo que eu vi no Google Books, são atualmente as mais comuns no Brasil. Não me apercebi que tenham chegado a Portugal, mas são imediatamente compreensíveis: eu compreendi os exemplos seguintes antes de consultar o Houaiss:

> A “batalha de Barcelona”, o grande **tira-teimas** entre as seleções do Brasil e da Argentina, afinal se resumiu a um confronto desigual entre o time que está jogando o melhor futebol do mundo e uma equipe com os nervos em [não consigo apanhar o resto]
>   [(*Veja*, nº 722-29, 1982)](https://www.google.pt/search?num=50&espv=2&biw=1242&bih=585&tbm=bks&q=%22mundo%20e%20uma%20equipe%20com%20os%20nervos%20em%22&oq=%22mundo%20e%20uma%20equipe%20com%20os%20nervos%20em%22&gs_l=serp.3...4621.7541.0.7947.2.2.0.0.0.0.87.159.2.2.0....0...1c.1.64.serp..0.0.0.8k3PhOPqwks)
>
> É impressionante. Hoje a gente vê pela TV até o branco do olho do jogador que vai bater uma falta, vê **tira-teimas** computorizados mostrando que, sim, o jogador estava 6,83 centímetros adiantado, logo o juiz é cego e incompetente.
>   [(“A regra é clara?” *Placar*, julho de 2000.)](https://books.google.pt/books?id=hOLYvPxS2-oC&pg=PA92&dq=%22tira-teimas%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjRr6fZ64zPAhVDWhQKHbQXDawQ6AEI2AEwGg#v=onepage&q=%22tira-teimas%22&f=false)

A aceções ‘instrumento de castigo’ e ‘dicionário’ parecem-me raras atualmente. Encontrei [este exemplo de 2015](https://books.google.pt/books?id=WInFPweHWHYC&pg=PT18&dq=%22tira-teimas%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiHnKHcio3PAhXEuBQKHZJfCXUQ6AEIUTAH#v=onepage&q=%22tira-teimas%22&f=false) em que o **tira-teimas** não é um dicionário, mas é um livro que decide uma disputa. De resto encontrei apenas exemplos antigos. Deixo aqui dois:

> A cambalear, como um ébrio, Manoel exigiu que o Antoninho Postiço escarrasse p'ra ali tudo quanto sabia, de contrário o varapau seria o **tira teimas**.
>   [(Delfim de Brito Guimarães, *Ares do Minho*, 1908.)](https://www.google.pt/search?num=50&espv=2&biw=1242&bih=585&tbm=bks&q=%22de%20contr%C3%A1rio%20o%20varapau%20seria%20o%20tira%20teimas%22&oq=%22de%20contr%C3%A1rio%20o%20varapau%20seria%20o%20tira%20teimas%22&gs_l=serp.3...1940.4390.0.4704.2.2.0.0.0.0.82.159.2.2.0....0...1c.1.64.serp..0.0.0.cMy2GO9t_HU)
>
> Em primeiro lugar este livro de versos manda-nos ir ao diccionario, logo por causa do titulo *Oaristos?* — que diabo é, ou são, *oaristos?* … E o meu diccionario, que eu considerava como fonte inesgotavel do mais imprevisto palavriado, nada me diz sobre *oaristos*. De *oanani*, também chamado *coqueiro-onnacu-curuí*, salta logo o meu **tira-teimas** para *oasiano* ! quanto a *oaristos* — moita!
>   [(*A Illustração — Vol. 7*, 1891)](https://books.google.pt/books?id=d6BRAQAAMAAJ&q=%22tira-teimas%22&dq=%22tira-teimas%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiH2eWs4IzPAhVDuRQKHYGKD2g4lgEQ6AEIpgEwFg)

O uso de *tira-teimas* no título da pergunta parece-me muito livre e fora do uso habitual. Este pressupõe uma disputa qualquer, o que não parece ser o caso no título da pergunta.

Comment: Jacinto, então no meu título deveria ter escrito "O" no início?

Comment: @Anoldmaninthesea. Acrescentar ***O*** daria ênfase, mas não me parece necessário. Seria como *Guia/O guia para o uso...* Mas como acrescentei na resposta, *tira-teimas* é usado duma forma fora do habitual no teu título.

Comment: Tira-teima é o mesmo que um jogo de tirar dúvidas. Portanto, o título faz sentido.

Comment: @AndréLyra Tens alguma fonte para apoiar o que afirmas?

Comment: Obrigado Jacinto ; )

Comment: Fontes: durante as transmissões de futebol da Rede Globo de Televisão quando ocorre um lance duvidoso o apresentador chama o "tira-teima" para analisarem o lance seja com linhas de impedimento virtuais ou exibição do lance por vários ângulos; existe um jogo de tabuleiro da Grow chamado Tira-Teima

Comment: O google dá esses significados : tira-teima
substantivo masculino

    1.
    m.q. TIRA-TEIMAS ('prova categórica', 'dicionário', 'objeto').
    2.
    infrm. arma de fogo portátil; revólver, pistola.
    3.
    desp B lance ou jogo entre adversários para decidir quem é o melhor.
    4.
    tv B recurso eletrônico que analisa trechos selecionados de imagens gravadas, esp. lances de competições esportivas, avaliando detalhes que tenham suscitado dúvidas na exibição em velocidade normal.
    5.
    SE infrm. aguardente de cana; cachaça.

Comment: @AndréLyra Sim, isso é o Houaiss que eu tenho na resposta. Mas o que a pergunta pede não é um jogo para decidir quem é o melhor; nem uma análise de imagens gravadas; nem uma prova categórica para decidir quem tem razão. Chamar *tira-teimas* a um esclarecimento acerca do uso de uma expressão, que é como *tira-teimas* é usado do título, é um uso fora do habitual.

Comment: A teima não é a pergunta dele, e ele não quer tirá-la? Pelo título era esperado que ele propusesse os tira-teimas na questão abaixo, mas não o fez. Mesmo assim o título propõe o jogo.

Comment: @AndréLyra Eu nunca vi *tira-teimas* usado dessa maneira, e ontem vi imensos exemplos. Sempre vi *tira-teimas* usado quando há uma discórdia, e quer-se saber quem tem razão: qual é o time melhor? houve falta ou não houve falta? Mas se tu conheces exemplos de uso do tipo do título dele, eu gostaria de os ver.